# Finding where there isn't a .join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have the Question.rb (has_one :answer) and the Answer.rb (belongs_to :question).

I would like to output, in the view, the number of unanswered questions. I would think it would be something like:

```
Question.where(answer.blank?)
```

or

`Question.notJoin(:answers)`

I know my syntax is way off and I'm not too sure if this would be a model scope or a controller instance variable, but I don't see why this wouldn't be easy to accomplish with rails.

Could anyone point me in the right direction here - I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `left join` between `questions` and `answers` as follows:

```
Question.joins(
  'left join answers on questions.id = answers.question_id'
).where(answer: { id: nil })
```

This would give you all the questions that do not have an answer.

You could place this query in a scope or a class method, or use it in a method.  That is really your choice.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add an answers counter cache to Question and then select based on that.

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :question, :counter_cache => true
```

Then add a scope to Question

```
scope :no_answers, -> { where(:answers_count => 0) }
```

Then it reads great

```
Question.no_answers
```